# How to get the date 7 days earlier date from current date in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I am using

```
DateFormat dateFormat = 
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
Date date = new Date();
String fromdate = dateFormat.format(date);
```

to get the current date, how can I get the date 7 days back. For example, if today is 7th June 2013, how can I get 31th May 2013 in the same format as defined in date formatter?

### Update

Got the solution:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

        Date date = new Date();
        String todate = dateFormat.format(date);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
        Date todate1 = cal.getTime();    
        String fromdate = dateFormat.format(todate1);
```

Comment: just think of it as rolling a calendar that you would generally do on your wrist watch http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/calendar_roll.htm

Answer (score 61):

You can use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
System.out.println("Date = "+ cal.getTime());
```

But as @Sean Patrick Floyd mentioned , [Joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is the best Java library for Date.

Comment: Can't edit it cause it's only one character, but it is missing a semicolon at the end of the first line or it won't compile.

Answer (score 22):

Or use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

```
DateTime lastWeek = new DateTime().minusDays(7);
```

Comment: new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(7, TimeUnit.DAYS));

Answer (score 12):

You can use this to continue using the type **Date** and a more legible code, if you preffer:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;
...
Date yourDate = DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), *days here*);
```

Answer (score 11):

Java now has a pretty good built-in date library, [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) bundled with [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29).

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DateTimeFormatter format =
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        LocalDateTime then = now.minusDays(7);

        System.out.println(String.format(
            "Now:  %s\nThen: %s",
            now.format(format),
            then.format(format)
        ));
        /*
            Example output:
                Now:  2014-05-09T14:51:48Z
                Then: 2014-05-02T14:51:48Z
         */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the Calendar-API:

```
// get Calendar instance
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());

// substract 7 days
// If we give 7 there it will give 8 days back
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)-6);

// convert to date
Date myDate = cal.getTime();
```

Hope this helps. Have Fun!

Answer (score 1):

For all date related functionality, you should consider using Joda Library. Java's date api's are very poorly designed. Joda provides very nice API.