# Comparing 2 dates javafx

Tags: java, hibernate, date, javafx, javafx-2

I'm writing an application which is based on javafx/hibernate. Now i
have problem when i want to make new table with articles that are sold
last 7/30/365 days (or custom date chosen).

- articles are stored in database with current date (`Date articleDate = new Date();` )
- all articles are fetched from database when the program is started and they are in an `ObserveList` named `articlesDBList`.

What i have tried so far:

```
ObserveList<ArticlesDB> sortForSevenDays =FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 
for(ArticleDB article: articleDBList) {
    if() { //missing statement for comparing articles by date for past 7 days
        sortForSevenDays.add(article);
    }
}
```

Comment: you will get help from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982056/how-to-get-the-date-7-days-earlier-date-from-current-date-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/) there are 3 possibilities in comparing `Date` in Java. In the comment section even the better choice (IF Javaversion < 8) of [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is presented.

The simpliest Solution without Joda would probably be just to compare using `Calendar`:

```
Calendar articleCal = Calendar.getInstance();
articleCal.setTime(articleDate);
//check for past 7 days
Calendar check = Calendar.getInstance();
check.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
if(articleCal.after(check)) 
    sortForSevenDays.add(article);
```

INFO: Just keep in mind, that this compares for exactly 7 days (incl. minutes etc.).